# Unable to push and pull from Azure repo. fatal: Unable to persist credentials with the 'wincredman' credential store

Tags: windows, git, azure

Starting a new job and I am trying to configure my Windows machine to properly push to a repository. We use Azure for source control. When I cloned the repo I used https and generated new credentials to use the repository.

Now every time I try to perform a push or pull to this repository, I see this error in the terminal.

```
fatal: Unable to persist credentials with the 'wincredman' credential store.
See https://aka.ms/gcm/credstores for more information.
```

Running `git config --list` I get:

```
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=schannel
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
pull.rebase=false
credential.helper=manager
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
init.defaultbranch=develop
credential.helper=manager
core.repositoryformatversion=0
```

At the same time, I am prompted to enter a password for the https repo. If I generate new credentials, I can enter a new password and the push/pull succeeds.

None of my coworkers need to constantly generate new credentials and ideally, I would like to configure things so that I don't either.

Comment: Try switching to the 'manager' credential, i think credential store 'wincredman' is creating the prb.

Comment: @MohamedAzarudeenZ Thanks. Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: sure, before that - Open the Windows Credential Manager (Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager).
Look for any credentials related to your Azure DevOps repository.
If you find any, try removing them and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it here so it will be easy for you to follow,
First
Open the Windows Credential Manager (Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager).
Look for any credentials related to your Azure DevOps repository.
If you find any, try removing them and see if that resolves the issue.

Else

Open a Git Bash or Command Prompt.

```html
git config --global credential.helper manager
```